# How to find files in a folder with regex and move them to a different folder

Tags: python

I want to organise my files by moving a certain group of files to an already existing folder.

I have created a regex code that identifies which files to be moved. I have then looped through the directory. I now need to move all the identified files to the already existing folder.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import shutil, os, re

fileContent = re.compile(r'''^(.*?)?
                (content)
                (.*?)$
                ''', re.VERBOSE)

for file in os.listdir('../Documents'):
    mo = fileContent.search(file)

    shutil.move(mo, '../Documents/Writing')
```

An error message is being thrown that says

> TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or
>   integer, not NoneType

I am not sure how to remedy this.

Comment: I've a few questions, first can you tell me what _content_ is and second which line of code is causing the error. As a side note please format the code within a code block

Comment: Why are you not using glob instead of regex?

Comment: @ChrisOH All the files I need to match have the word 'content' in them.

Comment: @ChrisOH 
  line 22, in <module>
    shutil.move(mo, '../Documents/Writing')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 556, in move
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 88, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 96, in samefile
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType

Comment: @ChrisOH That is the majority of the error message above. Sorry for the poor format. So I assume it is the last line of code that is causing the error: shutil.move(mo, '../Documents/Writing') .  Thanks Chris!

Comment: @utks009 I am very new to coding and I'm not familiar with glob, but I will look into it if it is a more efficient way of performing this task - Thank you!

Comment: Can you print out mo for me, the problem is that mo can be empty. `fileContent.search()` returns the directory if it fits the regex and empty list otherwise, which is what's causing your error

Comment: @ChrisOH When I print mo, there are lots of 'None' and matches. But the first line is 'None', so maybe that's the issue. So I guess my question is, how do I run through each match in mo and move that matched file to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change your code to something like this, this checks that mo returns a value before attempting the move

```py
import shutil, os, re

fileContent = re.compile(r'''^(.*?)?
                (content)
                (.*?)$
                ''', re.VERBOSE)

for file in os.listdir('../Documents'):
    mo = fileContent.search(file)
    if (mo):
        shutil.move(mo, '../Documents/Writing')
```